# How I can change the mimetype to render in VSCode Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

How I can change the mimetype to render in VSCode Jupyter Notebook like jupyter notebook or colab?

in VSCode Jupyter Notebook show only output like this picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diS8J.png)

but in jupyter notebook/colab show like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBTre.png)

I want to change like jupyter notebook/colab. please help me

Answer (score 0):

For now, the jupyter notebook in VSCode only can accept the inputs in the input box.

So you can switch to python file and execute it in the terminal(right-click -> Run Python File in Terminal).